# Confusión con CSS

Tags: css

Soy principiante en la programación, estoy estudiante html y css y me encuentro estancada porque los estilos css no se están aplicando correctamente en mis archivos html, algunos formatos los pone otros no, por ejemplo, si le pongo background, width, hight, solo se pone el background y lo demás no se le aplica y así sucede con otras términos usados en css. Necesito ayudo chicos. Gracias..

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y muestra el código necesario para poder identificar el problema y del mismo modo indica cual es el resultado esperado y cual estas obteniendo

Comment: Podrías compartir tu código de la hoja de cascada? (CSS)

Comment: Hola Ana, podrías compartir tu codigo, creo que el problema que estas teniendo es porque tienes archivos css que se estan sobreescribiendo o puedo ser por problemas de especificidad que viene a ser que un atributo tiene mayor prioridad que otro, o puede ser por problemas de cascada.

Comment: Pero primero tendrías que compartir tu código para poder ver si se trata de unos de los problemas que te comenté.